# {plotrix} - gap.plot - colors and background of points

Tags: r, plotrix

I am using the `gap.plot` function from the plotrix package. I would like to have the following points:

- circles in black (often written `pch=21, col="black"`)
- with a background in a chosen color (e.g. `col="red"`)

However, it doesn't seem to work on `gap.plot`:

- the `col` does set the color to black
- but the `bg` does not fill the background of the points with the chosen color (strangely, it does color the "cut" part of the plot, see below).

[image: gap.plot with attempts]
Here is some code, showing various attempts following reading of  [this link](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/gap.plot) and [that link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-September/252574.html).

**EDIT: better description of the question** Problems are:

- gap.plot() attempts do not have a red background
- points() gives black circle with red background, but the "y" value is false (normally y=12.5, but here I get y=21 instead; because of the gap).

Do you know how to obtain black circle filled with color?

```
library(plotrix)
x=seq(from=0,to=18,by=2)
y=rep(15,10)
CEX=1

## plots
x11()
# gap.plot()  with pch=21   col="black"   bg="red"
gap.plot(x,y+2.5, gap=c(1,9), gap.axis="y", xlim=c(0,25), ylim=c(0,25),
type="b",cex=CEX,col=rep("black",length(x)),bg=rep("red",length(x)),
pch=rep(21,length(x)))
text(22,9.5,labels="gap.plot() with pch=21",col="blue", cex=0.85)

# gap.plot()  with pch=19.  col="black"   bg="red"
gap.plot(x,y, gap=c(1,9), gap.axis="y",xlim=c(0,25),
ylim=c(0,25),type="b",cex=CEX,col=rep("black",length(x)),
bg=rep("red",length(x)),pch=rep(19.,length(x)),add=TRUE)
text(22,7,labels="gap.plot() with pch=19.",col="blue", cex=0.85)

# points()    with pch=21   col="black"   bg="red"
points(x,y-2.5,type="b",col="black",bg="red",pch=21)
text(22,12.5,labels="points() is shifted up",col="blue", cex=0.85)
```

Comment: add pch=21 to the last one, pch=19 doesnt support bg color

Comment: Yes you're right, I forgot to add it to the code. I'll edit that. The problem with points() is that it is "shifted up" (i.e. the y is not respected because of the gap).

Comment: so your question wasnt about how to get colored points with black circles after all? you're really asking about how to line up the y for points? this is confusing

Comment: Ok, sorry. This question is indeed "how to get color points", but "in a gap.plot". Here, attempts using gap.plot() do not work (no red-filled points); the attempt with points() does not work either (the points are colored, but the points are drawn at a wrong place: "y" should be 12.5 but ends up being around 21 - I guess points() is not compatible with a gap.plot).

Comment: oh I get it now. i didn't really delve into the source code, but looks like if you pass *both* `bg` and `bgcol` it works, such as `gap.plot(x,y+2.5, gap=c(1,9), gap.axis="y", xlim=c(0,25), ylim=c(0,25), type="b",cex=CEX,col=1, bgcol = 'white', bg = 2, pch=21)`

Comment: And yes, it works. Thanks a lot. The bg/bgcol trick may not be a desired behaviour though; should I contact the maintainer of the function?

Comment: I think Ben might see this, he is pretty active around here but not the maintainer of the package. It's not really a bug per se since when you give `bg` without `bgcol`, r uses partial matching and thinks you want to use the named argument `bgcol` instead of passing `bg` onto `...` this is documented in r but not what was desired obviously. I think giving both arguments would be the easiest/straight-forward solution

Comment: Ok "partial matching" was the explanation then. Might explained another unexpected message I am getting from gap.plot now. Could you post an answer, so that I can accept it? Else I do it, but I am not sure it is the appropriate way. Thanks again for your time!